# Keeping label and radio buttons generated by Python / WTForms / Bootstrap all on the same line

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap-3, wtforms, radiobuttonlist

I'm using Python/Flask WTForms version 2.1 with Boostrap 3 CSS and I can't find a solution to this problem:

In the Python form generation code code I have this form element

```
searchtype = RadioField("Search type:", choices=[('any', 'Any names'), ('all', 'All names')])
```

and in the Flask template I have

```
<!-- radiobutton for search type -->
 {{form.searchtype.label}}{{form.searchtype(class_="list-inline")}}
```

he radio buttons are correctly generated inline by "list-inline"  but there is a line break after the label element which I would like to remove. However, I can't find any classes or styles to add to form.searchtype.label or form.searchtype which will make the radio buttons run on on the same line after the  element.

The generated HTML:

```
<label for="searchtype">Search type:</label>
<ul class="list-inline" id="searchtype">
<li><input id="searchtype-0" name="searchtype" type="radio" value="any">
<label for="searchtype-0">Any names</label></li>
<li><input id="searchtype-1" name="searchtype" type="radio" value="all"> 
<label for="searchtype-1">All names</label></li></ul>
```

Thanks in advance